# googleAnalyticsR/googleAuthR token seems to expire in shiny markdown

Tags: r, shiny

here's my problem.

I access Google Analytics API via R with googleAnalyticsR. The whole thing happens in a Markdown script. Local everything runs without problems. But when I load the script on a Shiny Sever the GA token seems to expire after a while (a few hours).

The server log gives the following error message:

Warning in gzfile(file, mode) :
  cannot open compressed file '.httr-oauth', probable reason 'Permission denied'

The script to create the token looks like this:

```
library(googleAuthR)

options(googleAuthR.client_id = "client-id",
        googleAuthR.client_secret = "client-secret")

gar_auth()
```

I read that I should add

```
googleAuthR.httr_oauth_cache = FALSE
```

to the options. But when I do this and try to create a new Token I get follwing error:

```
Error: option('googleAuthR.httr_oauth_cache') must be set to 
         valid cache file location, 
         not TRUE or FALSE - (example: '.httr-oauth')
```

Anybody Ideas?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not that the token expires, the package `googleAnalyticsR` takes care of refreshing it if needed.

The problem is that the token was not created on the server (I assume you created locally then pushed to server), hence the error:

```
Warning in gzfile(file, mode) : cannot open compressed file '.httr-oauth', probable reason 'Permission denied'
```

The `shiny`user which runs your app does not have the permission to open that file. **I'm not a security expert** so take this lightly. You run the following from the root of your application (on your server) there error will go away.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 .httr-oauth
```

The above will let `shiny` access the file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You are right that the token is created locally and then pushed to the server. But the token will work for a certain time. That's why I thought the access expired.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem.I didn't give access to all users (777), but the Shiny App. Now the update of the token works well.